# Old router problem Can't enter setup

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I have an old router. When I try going into settings by going to 192.168.1.1 .Then I enter my user-name and password and click on OK and it asks for credentials again and then again and nothing else opens. It just keeps on asking for my user name and password.

Comment: Is your browser perhaps declining cookies?

Answer (score 4):

There should be a pinhole reset button on the router.  Use a paperclip and hold it in with the power on for about 15-20 seconds.  Afterwards look up the router's manual online to find the default username and password.

Comment: I did it. It does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you have entered the correct password?  If yes, check your browser.  If you are on a Windows-based PC, log into the router using Internet Explorer.  I have had problems logging into my router with Google Chrome in the past.

If you forgot your password, you should be able to do a reset by holding the pin-sized reset button down for a period of time.  Try 3 minutes to guarantee a reset.  Consult the documentation for the default IP, username, and password.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I'm stuck at the Username and Password box.